# SQL/Postgres: Get Single ACTIVE=Y Record from Group, ELSE Latest Date Record from Group

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using **Postgres**:

My `AGREEMENT_T` lists records that belong to a particular `agreement_group_id`. At any time, within a Group, either 1 is `ACTIVE=Y`, or 0 (at most 1).

```
ID   AGREEMENT_GROUP_ID  ACTIVE  FIELD1  FIELD2 STATUS_ACTION_DATE
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    55                  N       45      50     01-Oct-2021 00:03:05
2    55                  Y       78      70     30-Sep-2021 03:04:05
3    100                 N       44      4      02-Oct-2021 04:00:01
4    101                 N       1       2      02-Oct-2021 04:01:05
5    101                 N       0       1      05-Oct-2021 11:13:54
6    102                 Y       3       3      05-Oct-2021 11:47:45
7    102                 N       4       4      05-Oct-2021 11:48:49
```

I need to get a result that lists Agreement Group ID paired with

1. If `ACTIVE=Y` is available within a Group, then that Agreement ID
2. Else, the ID with the latest `STATUS_ACTION_DATE` for that Group

ex.

```
55   2
100  3
101  5
102  6
```

So far, I can pull up the latest `STATUS_ACTION_DATE` using Postgres' `array_agg(..)[1]` as follows,

```
SELECT agreement_group_id, (array_agg(id ORDER BY status_action_date DESC))[1] AS val
FROM ets.agreement_t 
GROUP BY agreement_group_id 
ORDER BY agreement_group_id
```

But is there a quick way to integrate that with finding `ACTIVE=Y`, maybe without using an extra `SELECT EXISTS`? Also something that performs well.

Answer (score 2):

You may use ROW_NUMBER to create a filter as shown below:

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
     *
FROM (
   SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY agreement_group_id 
             ORDER BY ACTIVE DESC, STATUS_ACTION_DATE DESC
        ) as rn
   FROM agreement_t
) t
WHERE rn=1;
```

| id | agreement_group_id | active | field1 | field2 | status_action_date | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 55 | Y | 78 | 70 | 2021-09-30T00:00:00.000Z | 1 |
| 3 | 100 | N | 44 | 4 | 2021-10-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1 |
| 5 | 101 | N | 0 | 1 | 2021-10-05T00:00:00.000Z | 1 |
| 6 | 102 | Y | 3 | 3 | 2021-10-05T00:00:00.000Z | 1 |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
     agreement_group_id , id
FROM (
   SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY agreement_group_id 
             ORDER BY ACTIVE DESC, STATUS_ACTION_DATE DESC
        ) as rn
   FROM agreement_t
) t
WHERE rn=1;
```

| agreement_group_id | id |
| --- | --- |
| 55 | 2 |
| 100 | 3 |
| 101 | 5 |
| 102 | 6 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mWERv1FCWmUzMsfK7hNuR5/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on` and get a little creative with `order by`:  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9d240b97f28e54b5aa43c1b48608c3cf))

```
select distinct on (agreement_group_id)                                                                                             
       agreement_group_id, id                                                                                                                           
  from <your table>
 order by agreement_group_id                                                                                                        
        , case when active = 'Y' then 0 else 1 end                                                                                  
        , status_action_date desc;
```